# Spark each file to a dataset row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have many files in a directory, each file containing text spanning multiple lines.
Currently, I use the following code to read all those files to a spark dataset (>2.0)

```
   val ddf = spark.read.text("file:///input/*")
```

However, this creates a dataset where each row is a line, not a file. I'd like to have each file (as string) per row in the dataset.

How can I achieve this without iterating over each file and reading it in separately as `RDD`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `wholeTextFiles()` on `SparkContext`

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, String)] = spark.sparkContext
                                      .wholeTextFiles("file/path/to/read/as/rdd")
```

> **SparkContext.wholeTextFiles** lets you read a directory containing
>   multiple small text files, and returns each of them as **(filename,
>   content) pairs**. This is in contrast with textFile, which would return
>   one record per line in each file.

Comment: Beautiful answer, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @mrsrinivas's answer would be to group by `input_file_name`. Given the structure:

```
evan@vbox>~/junk/so> find .        
.
./d2
./d2/t.txt
./d1
./d1/t.txt
 evan@vbox>~/junk/so> cat  */*.txt
d1_1
d1_2
d2_1
d2_2
```

We can collect lists based on the input files like so:

```scala
scala> val ddf = spark.read.textFile("file:///home/evan/junk/so/*").
     | select($"value", input_file_name as "fName")
ddf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, fName: string]

scala> ddf.show(false)
+-----+----------------------------------+
|value|fName                             |
+-----+----------------------------------+
|d2_1 |file:///home/evan/junk/so/d2/t.txt|
|d2_2 |file:///home/evan/junk/so/d2/t.txt|
|d1_1 |file:///home/evan/junk/so/d1/t.txt|
|d1_2 |file:///home/evan/junk/so/d1/t.txt|
+-----+----------------------------------+

scala> ddf.groupBy("fName").agg(collect_list($"value") as "value").
     | drop("fName").show
+------------+
|       value|
+------------+
|[d1_1, d1_2]|
|[d2_1, d2_2]|
+------------+
```

Comment: Nice way of using `input_file_name` in a `groupBy`, didn't know that function :). Still, @mrsrinivas answer is a bit cleaner.

Comment: For sure, my answer is `DataFrame` all the way but using a `RDD` in this case is a bit better

Comment: True, but there's always the `toDF` function.